# HTTPS / HTTP mod_rewrite rules, strange interaction with subsequent CMS index.php rewrite

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

With the below rewrites in htaccess, **as expected**, this HTTPS request is *not* rewritten:

`https://example.com/system/anything`

**is not** re-written to

`http://example.com/system/anything`

But, unexpectedly, this HTTPS request is rewritten:

`https://example.com/preview/anything`

**is** re-written to

`http://example.com/index.php/preview/anything`

Why is this?

A couple other facts / observations:

`/system/` is an actual path on the server. But `/preview/` is not an actual path--it's a URL segment that makes sense in the CMS, e.g., `/index.php/preview/anything` is how the CMS gets the request for the `/preview/anything` URL.

Other non-system URLs do rewrite properly (from HTTPS to HTTP), and properly do get passed to index.php. E.g.,

`https://example.com/real`

**is** re-written to

`http://example.com/real`

Here is the full block of rules:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

 # Force HTTPS for System URLs
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system(.*)$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https://example.com/$1" [R=301,L]

 # Force HTTP for Other URLs, but not: system or preview
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(system|preview)/(.*)$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http://example.com/$1" [R=302,L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Any insights into why `/preview/` gets the weird treatment?

---

**Added:** Note that `/preview/anything` is getting a `302` redirect to `/index.php/preview/anything` -- and THAT'S a big part of what seems so weird / unexpected. It should not be getting a redirect in the final rule, just a rewrite.

Comment: Just found a similar, also unanswered, question: http://serverfault.com/questions/128554/order-of-mod-rewrite-rules-in-htaccess-not-being-followed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these rewrite rules in an `.htaccess` file? In this case [the `[L]` flag does not do what you think it does](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) — it stops processing of the current ruleset, but then the request is processed by Apache again, using `.htaccess` files appropriate for the rewritten URI, therefore your rules may be executed again. This does not happen for rules which are in the Apache configuration file (and not inside a `<Directory>` section) — in this case the `[L]` flag is handled as expected.

For your example, `https://example.com/preview/anything` is internally rewritten into `https://example.com/index.php/preview/anything` by the third rule; however, in order to process that request, Apache must read the `.htaccess` file again — and this time the URI matches your second rule, which returns a `302` redirect.

Apache 2.4.x [supports the `[END]` flag which stops such rewrite loops, unlike `[L]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end); solutions for earlier Apache versions are more complex.

If you want to make sure that Apache makes only a single pass over your rewrite rules, you may add the following rule before all others:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !=""
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

On the first pass `REDIRECT_STATUS` will be empty; on the second pass it will have a non-empty value (usually `200`), and the rule will match and really stop further rewrites.

In case such a rule is not appropriate (e.g., in some cases you need to handle rewritten URIs on the second pass), you can set an environment variable in rules which should be really final:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L,E=FINISH:1]
```

and add the following rule before all others:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_FINISH} !=""
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Note that during the second pass Apache prepends `REDIRECT_` to environment variable names which were defined during the first pass, therefore you need to set `FINISH`, but test `REDIRECT_FINISH`.

Alternatively, you may try to modify your matching conditions so that on the second pass URIs modified on the first pass will not be matched (e.g., insert `(index\.php/)?` into the regexp in the second rule).

Comment: Yes, the `L|Last` flag means *stop processing rules*, but as soon as the result of the rule is an alias (and the third rule makes an alias) this alias becomes a new entry for the rewrite engine, and all rules are applied on this new entry.

Comment: Yes! I totally see it now--and, it actually seems obvious, in retrospect. While I knew that the results of the 301/302 redirects would be run through the rewrite engine again, I didn't fully grasp that the result of the alias (third rule) would be as well. I had already fixed this in production by blocking `index\.php/preview` in the second rule, and it's great to now know about the options of using `REDIRECT_STATUS` or combo of `E=FINISH` and `REDIRECT_FINISH`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the last rule is introducing an absolute `http`-based redirect when it's being done, perhaps due to some bug or feature in Apache or mod_rewrite.

How about you break it down into two rules with an extra condition?

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the `http` scheme (instead of `https`) that bothers you? If so, you should look at the `RewriteBase` directive.

From the [mod_rewrite docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

> The **`RewriteBase`** directive specifies the URL prefix to be used for per-directory (htaccess) **`RewriteRule`** directives that substitute a relative path.
>
> This directive is required when you use a relative path in a substitution in per-directory (htaccess) context (...)

Comment: Thanks, but no. RewriteBase just has to do with the path, right? It doesn't recognize the protocol / scheme.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the '(.*)$' at the end of the RewriteCond statements, because you're not using the captured data anywhere.  You could simplify those 2 like so:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system [NC]
```

and
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(system|preview)/ [NC]

What I would also recommend is turning on RewriteLog and setting RewriteLogLevel to see exactly what apache is doing per request.  With apache 2.2 or less, it would be:

```
RewriteLog /var/log/apache2/rewrite.log
RewriteLogLevel 7
```

You should see step by step exactly what matches and what action apache took.